# Как загрузить проект с примером OpenCV в AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я скачал библиотеку OpenCV я разорхивировал ее и посмотрел, что там есть и в она содержит примеры использования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот они на скриншоте. Но когда я пробую открыть их с помощью AndroidStudio то она не понимает, что это приложение... Сначала я получаю такое сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я его игнорирую и потом я могу увидеть структуру, но студия не понимает что это приложение

вот так это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Все так. Просто нужно дополнительно пометить папку **src** как "Source Folder" (в дереве проекта на папке правой кнопкой и снизу найти Marked Directory As -> Source)

Comment: Да, но когда я нажимаю на папку src у меня нет так такого пункта  Marked Directory As -> Source и я проверил в других проектах там тоже нет такого... Я нажал правой кнопкой на папке src которая нарисована на скриншоте и там такого нет... Можете уточнить где точно находиться этот пункт?

Comment: В Idea это выглядит вот так https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FjUt/cRWdci4p1. В студии, по сути, должно быть похоже. Если такого нет, можно покапаться в настройках проекта (иконка справа от общих настроек на панели). Также может быть полезно подключение pom-файла (если есть)